# Trying to get my data to display on the view- codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, view

From my controller, I am able to get the session date to display on my view, I however an missing something in the syntax when it comes to displaying the data from my table. i.e $data['modelData']. How do I do that?
Controller:

```
function validation()
    {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');


        if ($this->form_validation->run()  == FALSE )
        {
            $this->load->view('login_form');
            //return false; 
        }
        else{

           $this->load->model('login_model');

            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
             //echo $email;
            // echo $password;
            $result = $this->login_model->match_login($email, $password);

            if ($result ==false) {
                echo "Invalid Cardinals";
             } 
             else 
             {
                $session = array(
                  'id'=>$result[0]['id'], 
                  'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                  'is_logged_in'=> 1
                );
                if (!$this->session->set_userdata($session)) {

                    $data['modelData'] = $result;
                    $data['sessionData'] = $session;

                    $this->load->view('dashboard_view', $data);
                }
                 else {
                    echo "Error in session";
                }                          
            }   
        }            
    }
```

**Model**

```
 class Login_model extends CI_Model{
 //client..model

    public function match_login($email, $password){

    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get('user');

    $result = $query->result_array();

    if (empty($result)) 
    {
        return false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return $result;
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: update the model's `match_login()` code

Comment: @bob add your model code. this `match_login($email, $password)`

Comment: @ Abdulla..please review above to see model

Comment: @bob check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**In Controller**

```
if (!$this->session->set_userdata($session)) { # Changed

    echo "Error in session";
}
else {

    $data['modelData'] = $result;
    $data['sessionData'] = $session;

    $this->load->view('dashboard_view', $data);
}
```

**In View**

```
// retrieving modelData
foreach ($modelData as $modelItem) {
    echo "Model ID is ".$modelItem['id'];
}

// retrieving sessionData
foreach ($sessionData as $sessionitem) {
    echo "Session ID is ".$sessionitem['id'];
    echo "Session Email is ".$sessionitem['email'];
}
```

Comment: @bob happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Replace:

```
if (!$this->session->set_userdata($session)) {
    $data['modelData'] = $result;
    $data['sessionData'] = $session;
    $this->load->view('dashboard_view', $data);
}
```

#### with

```
if ($this->session->set_userdata($session)) {
    $data['modelData'] = $result;
    $data['sessionData'] = $session;
    $this->load->view('dashboard_view', $data);
}
```

### Explantion:

You could not get data from the table since the set_userdata function returned true therefore the control statement ignored the statements if block.